# Change focus among figure canvas in TkInter

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm plotting 2 different figures within a TkInter window. I'm using TkInter because I'll add some buttons later on. Just FYI, the two figures have different sizes, because I will interact with only the big one, leaving the small one for other uses. When the window opens, the focus is always set on the small one, so I need to use the TAB to switch it to the big figure. I tried many combinations of `focus()` or `focus_set()` but no metter what I tried it always opened the window with the focus on the small figure.

What can I do?

I attach here a simple code showing my problem.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

from numpy import arange, sin, pi
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import sys
import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.wm_title("Embedding in TK")

f1 = Figure(figsize=(7.5,10), dpi=100)
a1 = f1.add_subplot(111)
f2 = Figure(figsize=(7.5,5), dpi=100)
a2 = f2.add_subplot(111)

t = arange(0.0,3.0,0.01)
s = sin(2*pi*t)

a1.plot(t,s)
a2.plot(t,s)

canvas1 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f1, master=root)
canvas2 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f2, master=root)
canvas1.show()
canvas2.show()
canvas1.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH)
canvas2.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.BOTH)

def print_key(event):
    print 'you pressed '+event.key

cid = f1.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', print_key)

#SOMETHIN MISSING HERE IN ORDER TO SET THE FOCUS ON THE BIGGER WINDOW

tk.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try changine the settings of the small figure to prevent it being allowed focus:

```
canvas2.get_tk_widget().configure(takefocus=False)
```

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work... Did it actually work for you? Maybe is something with my version of TkInter or Python.

Comment: i didn't have matplotlib, i've just installed it and tried it, its not just your install, it doesn't work on mine either, but when i manually take the focus away from the second plot it can't get it back, but i can't seem to switch the focus programatically...